# Is there an accepted way to backup gitlab for archival purposes?

Tags: backup, gitlab

The standard Gitlab backup process only supports restore to the exact same version. Is there a way to perform a backup that it will be easy to interact with several years in the future, many Gitlab versions hence?

The solution that comes to mind is to just perform a full backup of the machine that runs Gitlab, but this seems like an awfully big hammer, and restoring wouldn't exactly be a cake-walk.

It seems like there's no way to do this, but I hope I'm wrong.